# Can I lose a hat?

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

Yesterday I had the secret hat described as [Hairboat's Revenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270851), but now I have lost this hat, is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt very much you can lose a hat. Having also said that you don't appear to have pinged Jon anyhow (in order to fulfill the hat requirements), so you couldn't have got it.

(maybe you've mistaken it with the secret hats 007 and Odinson you've got)

Comment: thanks for the response nicael, but i´m pretty sure that i have the hats, in fact i have taken a picture of all my hats!

Comment: @Jorgesys You can post the screenshot then.

Comment: yes but i´m currently at work, i will upload later the image! =(.