# Are some hats manually awarded other than Archimedes?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015, secret-hats

This is just a curiosity that I had after reading this post: [Can I lose a hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271225/can-i-lose-a-hat)

Probably this is not the explanation here, but I was wondering if the Hairboat hat is awarded manually, which could somehow justify the hat being awarded "by error" and then removed.

Thereby, I am asking if any hat - outside of the evident Archimedes that need special rules because of its nature - is being awarded manually by the staff.

I know that answering this one now, during the bash, could probably cause spoilers and others problems, so it is perfectly fine if the staff prefers to wait before giving this info or only reveal it for the hats for which the award criteria is known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no other hats besides Archimedes (previously Eureka) that need to be manually awarded, at least not this year.

There *was* another one in a previous year that had to be manually awarded: the [Epic Punyon Beard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard).

Comment: WHAT ARE YOU DOING ANIMUSON PEOPLE ARE GOING TO STOP SENDING US BRIBES NOW

Comment: Psh, I said *need to be*, not *can't be*. :P

Comment: @Pops I'll send you a bribe if you make another hat that can be manually awarded by offering bribes to people... Mafia style hat? You just look the other way now,... *leaves briefcase full of cash*

Comment: @Pops Where do you even spend Unicorn dollars now? I thought [tag:unicoins] was the future.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Unicoins were the future... in March, 2014. If you can find a bank that's willing to take them, please let me know.

Comment: @pops - I think I may know the mad one who actually sent you a request for the hat catalog / prices...