# Are there hats that are awarded manually this year?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I came across this post, [Are some hats manually awarded other than Archimedes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271236/are-some-hats-manually-awarded-other-than-archimedes), which shows that there are hats that are manually awarded by the staff.

Also, there are badges, such as Not a Robot on Stack Overflow that are awarded manually.

Just curious if there's any hats that are manually awarded this year?

*(It's fine if the staff could answer this after Winter Bash, so that it won't cause spoilers)*

Comment: I have the hypothesis that *Trendsetter* may be manually awarded to hat arrangements that particularly please some judge. I am not sure though.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Seems like it isn't, initially I thought so too :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, no hats are manually awarded this year.